# jQuery get the image src

Tags: jquery

I hope when I click the button, I can get the specific img src and show the img src in the div class `img-block` block.

**HTML**

```
<button class="button">Click</button>
<div class="img1">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="img-block"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-block{
    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    right:10%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
.img1 img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var images = $('.img1 img').attr(src);
  alert(images);      
});
```

But now I face the problem is to get the img src.
So I use alert to make the test, the result is it alert nothing.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

src should be in quotes:

```
$('.img1 img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 14):

for full url use

```
$('#imageContainerId').prop('src')
```

for relative image url use

```
$('#imageContainerId').attr('src')
```

```js
function showImgUrl(){
  console.log('for full image url ' + $('#imageId').prop('src') );
  console.log('for relative image url ' + $('#imageId').attr('src'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='imageId' src='images/image1.jpg' height='50px' width='50px'/>

<input type='button' onclick='showImgUrl()' value='click to see the url of the img' />
```

Answer (score 8):

You may find likr

```
$('.class').find('tag').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with the HTML DOM (ie. `this`), the array selector `[0]` must be used to retrieve the jQuery element from the Javascript array.

```
$(this)[0].getAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score 3):

html :

```
<img id="img_path_" width="24" height="24" src=".." class="img-fluid" alt=“">
```

js:

```
$('#img_path_').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case this format worked on latest version of jQuery:

```
$('img#post_image_preview').src;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
 $('img').context.currentSrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('body').on('click','.button',function(){              
                    var imgsrc=$('.img1 img').attr('src');              
                    $(".img-block").append(imgsrc);
                })
            });
```