# Click Image to change value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a bit of advice/guidance. I have a selection of colour icons. What I want to acheive is that one someone clicks on the colour icon, it puts the name of the colour into a hidden text field.

So my hidden text field code is -

```
<form name=Data>
<input type=hidden id=colour name=colour size=7 maxlength=7>
</form>
```

I then have my table of icons. So what I want to achieve is that when someone clicks 'teal.png' it changes the value of the text field to 'teal'.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how best to achieve this please?

```
Select the background colour below<br><br><table class="radioiconstable"  width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   

<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/teal.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/grey.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/green.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/evergreen.png"></td>    

</tr>  

<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/brightred.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/crimson.png"></td>   
<td><img src="custom/icons/orange.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/yellow.png"></td>     
</tr>  
<tr>    
<td><img src="custom/icons/sand.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/brown.png"></td>
<td><img src="custom/icons/navy.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/coolblue.png"></td>     


</tr>  
<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/sky.png"></td> 
<td><img src="custom/icons/purple.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/pink.png"></td>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/candyfloss.png"></td>  

</tr>  

</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a free code writing service, it is expected that you attempt to solve your problem and then ask a question when you get stuck with a specific problem with your code.  Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: You can copy paste one of the answers and it will work. But breaking up your problem and searching for solutions are important skills of a programmer. You can search about 1) [How to add click event handler in jquery?](https://api.jquery.com/click/). 2) [How to get the `src` of an image element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937162/jquery-get-the-image-src). 3) [How to set the value of an input element?](http://api.jquery.com/val/). You'll learn so much in the process of implementing this. If you're still stuck you can post it on here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function I have written below. It might not be the best if the URLs will change (adding more `'/'` after the file name for example).

What the function does is first it gets the image src of the clicked image and splits the SRC by `'/'`. Because the filename is always last in your example you want to grab the last value `url.length - 1`. To obtain the color you do the same, but now you only have green.png so you split by `'.'` and grab the first element in array (pos: 0).

```
$("img").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).prop('src').split("/");
    var file = url[url.length - 1].split(".")[0];

  $("#colour").val(file);
})
```

```js
$("img").click(function(){
 var url = $(this).prop('src').split("/");
 var file = url[url.length - 1].split(".")[0];
  
  $("#colour").val(file);
  
  console.log(file)
})
```

```css
img{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name=Data>
<input type=hidden id=colour name=colour size=7 maxlength=7>
</form>

Select the background colour below<br><br><table class="radioiconstable"  width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   

<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/teal.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/grey.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/green.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/evergreen.png"></td>    

</tr>  

<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/brightred.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/crimson.png"></td>   
<td><img src="custom/icons/orange.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/yellow.png"></td>     
</tr>  
<tr>    
<td><img src="custom/icons/sand.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/brown.png"></td>
<td><img src="custom/icons/navy.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/coolblue.png"></td>     


</tr>  
<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/sky.png"></td> 
<td><img src="custom/icons/purple.png"></td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/pink.png"></td>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/candyfloss.png"></td>  

</tr>  

</table>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please elaborate rather than just giving one for the sake of it.

Comment: plus 1 for your answer. I know the feeling when you write a correct answer and nobody votes you.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Thanks Alexandru. It's not about not voting, it's about downvoting and not justifying as to what the problem is, especially when the code does what OP is asking for :). Thanks anyway Alexandru.

Comment: yeah, i also dislike when i receive downvotes unjustified.

Comment: Take my +1, this is a great solution

Comment: It's most likely for answering an off topic question

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing the downvote was for answering a basic question in which OP hasn't tried anything.

Comment: @adiga I understand, not a fan of spoon-feeding myself, but I don't believe that deserved a down vote as OP only wanted advice/guidance how to achieve it which is exactly why I broke my answer down into steps at the start, what I did, why and final result.

Comment: I know, I know. It's not nice when you spend a lot of time to write a detailed answer and get downvoted. Evidently, some users are strict when it comes to spoon-feeding.

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be `attr('src')` instead of `prop('src')`?

Comment: @adiga No, I mean, both will work however "the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes." taken from JQuery docs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I got the `src` attribute of the `img` using the *jQuery* function [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

After that, I replaced the substrings `custom/icons/` & `.png` to get only the color from the `src` attribute using the [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

Finally, here is a *code snippet* demonstrating what I've did:

```js
$("td").on("click",function(){
var color=$(this).find("img").attr("src");
$("#colour").val(color.replace("custom/icons/","").replace(".png",""));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<table class="radioiconstable"  width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   

<tr>     
<td><img src="custom/icons/teal.png">IMAGE 1</td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/grey.png">IMAGE 2</td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/green.png">IMAGE 3</td>  
<td><img src="custom/icons/evergreen.png">IMAGE 4</td>    

</tr>  

</table>


<input type="text" id="colour" name="colour" size="7" maxlength="7">
```

Comment: don't know why this is downvoted - seems to do exactly what the OP is asking

Comment: @Stender I don't know why also :/ thanks for the support !

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi, +1 for your answer. I know the feeling when you write a correct answer and nobody votes you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Was only expecting a few pointers but you have exceeded my expectations. Thank you :)

Comment: @JamesHarding welcome, please don't forget to click on **Check Mark** to approve the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
var colorImages = document.querySelectorAll('td img');

colorImages.forEach(function(image){
    image.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var clickedImageURL = event.target.src;
        var color = clickedImageURL.replace('custom/icons/','').replace('.png','');
        document.querySelector('#colour').value = color;
    });
});
```

I'd suggest however adding attributes to those images that hold color value instead of getting it from a file name, for example: `<img src="custom/icons/yellow.png" data-color="yellow">`