# Jquery get image src array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with discord.js.
[jQuery get the image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937162/jquery-get-the-image-src)

looked for the most relevant article, but it's different from what I'm trying to do.

**I'd like to receive several srcs of img in the span tag by array.**

```html
<div class="jewel__wrap">
   <span id="gem00" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_000">
     <span class="jewel_img">
       <img src="https://xxx/60.png" alt=""> // this src
     </span>
     <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span>
   </span>
   <span id="gem01" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_001">
     <span class="jewel_img">
       <img src="https://xxx/50.png" alt=""></span> // this src
     <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

```js
const jewel = $(".jewel_level").text();
const jewel2 = $(".jewel_img").find('img').attr("src");

console.log("jewel : ", jewel, "jewel2 : ", jewel2);
```

jewel receives both lv.5 and ex) lv.5lv.5.
jewel2 only receives one src.

How should I bring it?

console

```
jewel : Lv.5Lv.5 jewel2 : https://xxx/60.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with jQuery's [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is...

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first** element in the set of matched elements

Instead, you can use jQuery's [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to transform a collection of elements into an array

```js
const sources = $(".jewel_img > img")
  .map((_, { src }) => src) // extract property
  .get() // get the array out of the jQuery object
  
console.log("sources", sources)
```

```html
<!-- minified HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="jewel__wrap"> <span id="gem00" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_000"> <span class="jewel_img"> <img src="https://xxx/60.png" alt=""> </span> <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span> </span> <span id="gem01" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_001"> <span class="jewel_img"> <img src="https://xxx/50.png" alt=""></span> <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span> </span></div>
```

---

You may even want to treat the text in a similar way and collect all the data into objects

```js
const data = $(".jewel_btn")
  .map((_, btn) => {
    const $btn = $(btn)
    return {
      image: $btn.find(".jewel_img img").attr("src"),
      level: $btn.find(".jewel_level").text()
    }
  })
  .get()
  
console.log("data", data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="jewel__wrap"> <span id="gem00" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_000"> <span class="jewel_img"> <img src="https://xxx/60.png" alt=""> </span> <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span> </span> <span id="gem01" class="jewel_btn" data-grade="3" data-item="E595062cGem_001"> <span class="jewel_img"> <img src="https://xxx/50.png" alt=""></span> <span class="jewel_level">Lv.5</span> </span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved what I couldn't do in the past few days.
It works well if I execute the **first code** you uploaded on the **comment snippet**, but when I execute it on my code, sources[] appears. Can I know which point is the problem?
The second code you uploaded is good at outputting image and level.

Comment: @appdev if you replaced your current line of code `const jewel2 = $(".jewel_img").find('img').attr("src")` with my answer code, it should work fine. If you're getting an empty array, you might be [running the code too early](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/283366)