# cant seem to get img src into variable

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to try and get the img src of a bunch of imgs in a div and storing the values as per code below... but i am getting undefined as the output of the variable `newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGSRC` - can anyone help as to why?

```
$('.newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGs img').each(function() {
let newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGSRC = $(this).attr('data-src');
console.log(newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGSRC);
});
```

Example of markup of the `newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGs` div is below:

```
<div class="newHomeHeroCarouselFetchedIMGs">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image1.jpg">
<img src="https://www.example.com/image2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a `data` attribute, just use `$(this).attr('src');`.

Comment: DOH!!!!! thanks - could not see that error for want of looking...

Comment: Does this answers your question? [jQuery get the image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937162/jquery-get-the-image-src)